# AppleScript doesn't stop running after exit repeat

Tags: applescript

I have the following code. It runs, and i get my result, i think something wrong with the exit repeat, after it get the ipad name, the script is still keep running until time out. 
Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the code? Thanks!

---

```
set deviceName to "iPad"
tell application "System Events"
tell process "iTunes"
    activate
    repeat with i from 1 to the count of (row of outline 1 of scroll area 2 of window "iTunes")
        repeat with j from 1 to the count of static text of row i of outline 1 of scroll area 2 of window "iTunes"
            set xxxx to the value of item j of static text of row i of outline 1 of scroll area 2 of window "iTunes"
            if (xxxx contains deviceName) then
                print xxxx
                click row i of outline 1 of scroll area 2 of window "iTunes"
                exit repeat
            end if
            --exit repeat
        end repeat

    end repeat

end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exit the script after the first iPad is found, replace exit repeat with return.

Answer (score 0):

The problem (you ask for) is that you have an repeat in an repeat. That means when you're in the sub-loop and exit the repeat you will jump to the main loop. To exit from here you have to an exit repeat again.

Looking at your code I don't understand the nested repeat loop. You can remove the surrounded/main repeat and It will work as expected.

```
set deviceName to "iPad"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "iTunes"
        activate
        repeat with UIElement in rows of outline 1 of scroll area 2 of window "iTunes"
            if (value of static text of UIElement as text) begins with deviceName then return select UIElement
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

The reason I use an begins with is that contains will click the previous purshcase menu items.